# Cannot set consistency level when querying Amazon Keyspaces service from DataGrip

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, datagrip, amazon-keyspaces

I'm trying to perform inserts on Amazon's Managed Cassandra service from IntelliJ's DataGrip IDE, however I recieve the following error:

```
Consistency level LOCAL_ONE is not supported for this operation. Supported consistency levels are: LOCAL_QUORUM
```

This is due to Amazon using the `LOCAL_QUORUM` consistency level for writes.

I tried to set the consistency level with `CONSISTENCY LOCAL_QUORUM;` before running other queries but it returned the following error:

```
line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'CONSISTENCY' ([CONSISTENCY])
```

From my understanding, this is because `CONSISTENCY` is a cqlsh command and not a CQL command.

I cannot find any way to set the consistency level from within DataGrip so that I can run scripts and populate my tables.

Ultimately, I will use plain cqlsh if I cannot find a solution but I was hoping to use DataGrip as I find it useful and have many databases already configured. I hope someone can shed some light on the issue, this seems like it should be a basic feature.

Comment: It could be JDBC driver issue and desired method haven't implemented yet. Since you're trying to run pure cqlsh command as SQL

Comment: Follow the issue [DBE-10638](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10638).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am Max from DataGrip team, and the correct answer is:

It could be JDBC driver issue and the desired method hasn't been implemented yet. Since you're trying to run pure `cqlsh` command as SQL. Follow the issue [DBE-10638](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10638).

Answer (score 2):

It's a DataGrip bug, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10182 :

> Cassandra 'CONSISTENCY' command is not supported

So upvote that bug, and maybe add a comment that it makes DataGrip useless for writing to Amazon Managed Cassandra

Comment: I've seen this before, though I was hoping it would've been included in the latest release as the issue seems to be fixed. I will wait to see if any alternatives come up in the meantime.

Comment: Syntax highlighting in this situation is not applicable since it's cqlsh command.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Keyspaces (Apache Cassandra)

Now I used **DataGrip** version **2020.1.3 (Buy Licensed)**

Encounter problems as well.

Cannot change type CONSISTENCY **ONE** to **LOCAL_QUORUM**

I have opened an issue already and waiting for the investigation.

> 

So, I try so many tools and found that **DBeaver** is working,

The **CONSISTENCY can be selected in the configuration GUI.**

[image]

https://dbeaver.com/download